# Replace repeating variables by "NA" using awk

Tags: unix, awk

Suppose I have the next file:

```
1 Blue
2 Red
3 Yellow
4 Yellow
5 Yellow
6 Purple
7 Purple
8 Green
```

And I would like to get the following file, replacing the repeated variables by "NA"

```
1 Blue
2 Red
3 Yellow
4 NA
5 NA
6 Purple
7 NA
8 Green
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this -

```
$ awk 'a[$2]++{$2="NA"} 1' f
1 Blue
2 Red
3 Yellow
4 NA
5 NA
6 Purple
7 NA
8 Green
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print $1, ($2==p ? "NA" : $2); p=$2}' file
1 Blue
2 Red
3 Yellow
4 NA
5 NA
6 Purple
7 NA
8 Green
```

Comment: Right, there are 2 possible correct solutions to this problem - mine if the repeated values are contiguous as shown in the question, @VipinKumar's if the repeated values are not contiguous or if they are contiguous but you don't care about loading all the $2 values into memory. Chances are Vipin's is the right approach unless the input file is huge or you specifically do not want to replace disconnected repeated values.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{ if ($2 == COLOR) {print $1, "NA"} else {COLOR=$2; print $1, $2 } }'
```